# How I can know if there is at least one type of file in a directory?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010

For example: I want to know if there are images in a directory (eg. ".jpg") I want to return a boolean value that confirm whether there are files with that extension or not.

At first I started with the following code:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim Path1 As String
    FolderBrowserDialog1.ShowDialog()
    Path1 = FolderBrowserDialog1.SelectedPath
    TextBox1.Text = FolderBrowserDialog1.SelectedPath 'ignore this
    If System.IO.File.Exists(Path1 + "\*.jpg") = True Then
        Label1.Text = "At least there is a .jpg"
    End If
End Sub
```

It did not work and I thought use System.IO.Directory.GetFiles.The problem is how I can use it to give me back a value true / false, or rather to see if there is such file types

Comment: Post the code you tried, and explain what you mean by "not successful"

Comment: Well, what's wrong with that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [Directory.EnumerateFiles](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd413233.aspx%27) along with [Enumerable.Any](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.any.aspx):

```
Dim exists As Boolean = Directory.EnumerateFiles(folderName, "*.jpg").Any()
```

`GetFiles` should also work (if you're in .NET 3.5), but will be less efficient:

```
Dim exists As Boolean = Directory.GetFiles(folderName, "*.jpg").Any()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Private Function FileExists(folderPath As String, extension As String) As Boolean
    Return (Directory.GetFiles(folderPath, "*." + extension).Length <> 0)
End Function
```